# How to make cell formatting faster for large worksheets in EPPlus

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I have a C# data processing application which uses EPPlus to write the final results into an excel sheet. The background color of the rows are changed based on what the data on that row signifies. Time was never an issue as I only dealt with files that were below <100MB before. However, as my requirements have changed and the files get larger, I have noticed that.. just coloring makes my application 60% slower. Removing coloring makes the application significantly faster. The snippet below is an example of the code which I use to color the data to make it visually distinguishing. I'm no expert at EPPlus but is there a way, this can be optimized to make my application faster? Or are there any better ways for me to make the rows visually distinct for the people who will end up looking at the data? Any help will be appreciated!

```
    if (data[4] == "3")
                                {
                                    // color the type 3 messages here
                                    var fill1 = cell1.Style.Fill;
                                    fill1.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
                                    fill1.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.LightGray);
}

                                if (data[4] == "4")
                                {
                                    var fill1 = cell1.Style.Fill;
                                    fill1.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
                                    fill1.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.BlanchedAlmond);
                                }
```

EDIT:

This is the code I use to copy the template and write the excel data into the new worksheet. `p` is an Excel Package which I convert to a byte Array before writing to the excel file.

```
        Byte[] bin = p.GetAsByteArray();
        File.Copy("C:\\Users\\mpas\\Desktop\\template.xlsx", "C:\\Users\\mpas\\Desktop\\result.xlsx");
        using (FileStream fs = File.OpenWrite("C:\\Users\\mpas\\Desktop\\result.xlsx")) { 
        fs.Write(bin, 0, bin.Length);
        }
```

Comment: Can you take a blank spreadsheet and set the sheet up with conditional formatting that will do your coloring.  Save it and use it as a template.  It can be copied to be the new output file.  Then when it is written to you will not have to pragmatically do the coloring

Comment: @MatthewD Good Idea, but since the application is supposed to produce multiple files every day... not sure if the template solution will be efficient

Comment: You can place the template with the exe. It will just be copied each time it is needed.  Then open, write, and save.  It could produce thousands a day.  It shouldn't matter.

Comment: @MatthewD okay, I get what you are saying now.. I'll give it a try. Thank you! Now I need to find out how to do conditional formatting in Excel lol

Comment: @MatthewD Just tried your approach, after copying the template EEPlus basically overwrites everything and the conditional formatting goes away with it. It basically starts with a empty sheet with no formatting. Not sure how I can lock the conditional formatting

Comment: Are you sure it is not creating a new file?  I open existing workbooks and all the formatting and data is there as expected.  Can you paste you code ab0ve where you copy the file and where you open it with EPPlus

Comment: I ask because I think there are different ways to open an existing file and create a file from scratch

Answer (score 2):

Styling is much faster in EPPlus, and most Excel APIs, if you use named styles. Assign and use the style to cell in EPPlus like this ...

```
internal static string YourStyleName = "MyStyle";
ExcelNamedStyleXml yourStyle = excel.Workbook.Styles.CreateNamedStyle(YourStyleName);
yourStyle.Style.Font.Color.SetColor(Color.DarkRed);
yourStyle.Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
yourStyle.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.LemonChiffon);

// ...
sheet.Cells[sourceRange].StyleName = YourStyleStyleName
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is code to open an existing file.

```
        FileInfo AddressList = new FileInfo("c:\test\test.xlsx");

        // Open and read the XlSX file.
        try
        {
            using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(AddressList))
            {
                // Get the work book in the file
                ExcelWorkbook workBook = package.Workbook;
                if (workBook != null)
                {
                    if (workBook.Worksheets.Count > 0)
                    {

                        // Get the first worksheet
                        //ExcelWorksheet Worksheet = workBook.Worksheets.First();
                        var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
```

Comment: Ahhh. The byte array and filestream might be doing it...  EPPlus probably would not disturb it if you were writing cell by cell    worksheet.Cells["E" + lRow.ToString()].Value = "blah"   But that is going to be slower.

Comment: @sparta93 Have you tried applying the formats without doing the var fill1 and then setting the properties on that. Maybe try just applying them straight to the cell.  Also if this is just a bunch of if statements. it is going to run each if to check the condition.  If you did a switch i believe that once it matches it's case it will not check the rest.  I believe that will help your speed greatly

Comment: @sparta93 Does there happen to be one that is the condition that is true 95% of the time?  If so, you could put that one in the if and then use "else if" for the rest of the conditions.  That way it will hit first for those and the other conditions will never get checked.